# How do you set numpy array elements to zero according to length vector

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Say I have the following array `d`:

```
>>> d = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
>>> d
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

And I have vector `l` that tells me the length of each row in `d`:

```
>>> l = np.array([2,2,3,4,5])
>>> l
array([2, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

How do you zero out elements in `d` rows that are longer than specified in `l`, to get this:

```
>>> # zero out end of rows in `d`
>>> d
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 11, 12,  0,  0],
       [15, 16, 17, 18,  0],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

This is for tensorflow, so the tf equivalent would be even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to create the mask of the trailing places in a vectorized manner and then simply reset those in the input array with `boolean-indexing`, like so -

```
d[l[:,None] <= np.arange(d.shape[1])] = 0
```

Equivalent of the extension of `l` to `2D` : `l[:,None]` in `tensorflow` would be: `tf.expand_dims(l, 1)` or `tf.expand_dims(l, -1)`.

Sample run -

```
In [83]: d
Out[83]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [84]: l = np.array([2,2,3,4,5])

# mask of trailing places
In [85]: l[:,None] <= np.arange(d.shape[1])
Out[85]: 
array([[False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [86]: d[l[:,None] <= np.arange(d.shape[1])] = 0

In [87]: d
Out[87]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 11, 12,  0,  0],
       [15, 16, 17, 18,  0],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Comment: how would that work for tf.expand_dims(l, 1)? d[tf.expand_dims(l,1) <= np.arange(d.shape[1])] = 0 doesn't seem to work

Comment: @vega Sorry I don't know much about tensorflow to answer that. All I knew was the expansion part.

Comment: No worries! Np should be fine! Thanks.